# installing printer driver on Microsoft Surface 2

Tags: drivers, printer, windows-8.1, windows-rt

I'm trying to install a driver for my networked [Epson NX420](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supDetail.jsp?oid=151211&infoType=Downloads&platform=OSF_M_X7) printer on my **Microsoft Surface 2** tablet. Of course I get the error: `This APP can't run on your PC.`  Now after searching for information, Microsoft wants you to install the generic printer driver on the tablet. I did this and my printer wasted 30 pages with non-encoded characters.

Could I manually copy the printer drivers somehow from another Windows 8 computer and put them on here? I remember back in Windows 98 there was an option to view all necessary drivers for a printer by using Device Manager (the dll, ini's, etc. usually in the System32 folder).  I don't see this option in Windows 8.

Any suggestions?

Comment: those won't work. try calling epson.

Answer (score 1):

Select the "Epson ESC/P-R V4 Class" printer driver from the list of printers instead of the NX420 when connected a network or WIFI.  At least it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The [Surface 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_2) is a [Windows RT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_RT) based system and here you can't use normal x86/x64 software. Also the [driver support is very limited](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/CompatCenter/ProductDetailsViewer?Type=Hardware&Name=Epson%20Stylus%20NX420%20All-in-One%20Printer&ModelOrVersion=C11CA80201&Vendor=Epson&Locale=1033,2057,3081,4105,16393&LastSearchTerm=Epson%2bNX420&BreadcrumbPath=Epson%20NX420&TempOsid=Windows%20RT), according to the Microsoft Compatibility Center.

Comment: Okay. I plugged the printer into the tablet USB directly and it installed with no problems. The device IS compatible with Windows RT. However, the device is a network printer. Why will it not find a driver when using it as a network printer?

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe the network printing is not available in RT. I don't have a RT device so I can't test this.